# Multiple choice quiz - issue with radio buttons and functions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to create a multiple choice quiz using simple functions and radio buttons in the HTML form tags but it is only allowing me to check one radio button for the whole quiz instead of one per question.

Also, the submit button is not activating the function `checkAll`, I don't know if this is because I am trying to do something impossible or simple because I'm just missing something. Any help would be appreciated!

The code is below. . . I'm only new to JavasScript and html as well as StackOverflow, so sorry if I'm doing anything wrong with this question.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var score=0;

function checkAll() {

function questioncheckOne(){
    var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("a3")
    if (correctAnswer.checked == true) {
        score++;
        alert("Correct, your score is now " +score)
    }
    else {
            alert("Wrong, your score is now " +score)
    }
};


function questioncheckTwo(){
    var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("b2")
    if (correctAnswer.checked == true) {
        score++;
        alert("Correct, your score is now " +score)
    }
    else {
            alert("Wrong, your score is now " +score)
    }
};


function questioncheckThree(){
    var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("c4")
    if (correctAnswer.checked == true) {
        score++;
        alert("Correct, your score is now " +score)
    }
    else {
            alert("Wrong, your score is now " +score)
    }
};


function questioncheckFour(){
    var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("d3")
    if (correctAnswer.checked == true) {
        score++;
        alert("Correct, your score is now " +score)
    }
    else {
            alert("Wrong, your score is now " +score)
    }
};


function questioncheckFive(){
    var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("e3")
    if (correctAnswer.checked == true) {
        score++;
        alert("Correct, your score is now " +score)
    }
    else {
            alert("Wrong, your score is now " +score)
    }
};

};
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name ="Where in the world is...?">

<p>

    Question1: Where in the world would you find the Spire? 

</p> 

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="a1" value="a1"  /> Kerry. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="a2" value="a1"  /> Galway. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="a3" value="a1"  /> Dublin. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="a4" value="a1"  /> Donegal. </input>


<p> 


    Question2: Where in the world would you find the Colosseum? 

</p> 


<input type="radio" name="radio" id="b1" value="a2"  /> Taipei. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="b2" value="a2"  /> Rome. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="b3" value="a2"  /> Reykjavic. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="b4" value="a2"  /> Brussels. </input>


<p> 

    Question3: Where in the world would you find the Taj Mahal? 

</p> 


<input type="radio" name="radio" id="c1" value="a3"  /> London. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="c2" value="a3"  /> Brisbane. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="c3" value="a3"  /> Paris. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="c4" value="a3"  /> Agra. </input>


<p> 

    Question4: Where in the world would you find the Parthenon? 

</p> 


<input type="radio" name="radio" id="d1" value="a4"  /> Edinburgh. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="d2" value="a4"  /> Oslo. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="d3" value="a4"  /> Athens. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="d4" value="a4"  /> Pyongyang. </input>


<p> 



    Question5: Where in the world would you find the Niagara Falls? 

</p>


<input type="radio" name="radio" id="e1" value="a5"  /> Hong Kong. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="e2" value="a5"  /> Moscow. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="e3" value="a5"  /> New York. </input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="e4" value="a5"  /> Ottawa. </input>



<p>

<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="checkAll()"  /> </input>

</p>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `checkAll()` function is running, but you don't actually invoke your other check functions inside of it; you just declare them. So it appears as though nothing is running. You'll also need to prevent the default submit action. One way to do that is by returning `false` at the end of that function.

Comment: Can you cut this down to the minimal (non-)working example? And use variables instead of copying functions over and over.

Comment: I should return false at the end of each function within the checkAll function? Would using variables mean I'd have to use arrays also, I understand it would be much more efficient but don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make the `name` attribute unique for each group of radio buttons. Currently, they are all named `radio`.

As for the `checkAll` function, the issue is that you are only defining the functions, never calling them. Within the `checkAll` function, actually call the other functions you've defined:

```
function checkAll() {
    // existing function definitions here

    questioncheckOne();
    questioncheckTwo();
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you check the radio button, all other buttons with the same name are unchecked. In your case, you'll want each question's radios to have a separate name (right now, they are all "radio")